# ASP.NET Core AJAX post

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I write this ASP.NET Core code but I have got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". In StartUp, I add Antiforgery with HeaderName = X-CSRF-TOKEN.

```
@model FinanceWorld.Web.ViewModels.Analyzes.AllAnalyzesViewModel
@{
this.ViewData["Title"] = "Analyzes";
}

<h1 class="text-center">@this.ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
@foreach (var analyze in Model.Analyzes)
{
    <div class="card col-md-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="@analyze.Image" class="card-img-top pt-3" alt="@analyze.Title">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">@analyze.Title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">@analyze.Description</p>
            <p class="card-text">@analyze.AddedByUserUserName</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form method="post" id="votesForm"></form>
            <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-around">
                <li class="d-inline" style="font-size: 35px" onclick="sendVote(@analyze.Id, 
true)">
                    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                </li>
                <li class="d-inline" style="font-size: 35px" onclick="sendVote(@analyze.Id, 
false)">
                    <i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    function sendVote(analyzeId, isUpVote) {
        var token = $('#votesForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
        var json = { analyzeId, isUpVote };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/votes",
            type: "Post",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#votesCount").html(data.votesCount);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
}

namespace FinanceWorld.Web.Controllers
{
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using FinanceWorld.Services.Data.Votes;
using FinanceWorld.Web.ViewModels.Votes;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class VotesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IVotesService votesService;

    public VotesController(IVotesService votesService)
    {
        this.votesService = votesService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult<PostVoteViewModel>> Vote(VoteInputModel model)
    {
        string userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        await this.votesService.SetVote(model.AnalyzeId, userId, model.IsUpVote);
        var votes = this.votesService.GetVotes(model.AnalyzeId);

        return new PostVoteViewModel { VotesCount = votes };
    }
}
}

namespace FinanceWorld.Web.ViewModels.Votes
{
public class VoteInputModel
{
    public string AnalyzeId { get; set; }

    public bool IsUpVote { get; set; }
}
}
```

I don't enter in the function sendVote(analyzeId, isUpVote) at all,
I hope this code will be useful, I'll implement it after that votesCount in View.
Please, if it's possible help me. I'll be grateful.

Comment: Can you post /api/votes controller action pls?

Comment: Thanks, and VoteInputModel  code pls too.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 var data = { AnalyzeId: analyzeId, IsUpVote: isUpVote };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/votes",
            data: data,
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#votesCount").html(data.votesCount);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
[Route("api/votes/vote")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PostVoteViewModel>> Vote(VoteInputModel model)
```

In Ajax

```
url: "/api/votes/vote",
```